# Magento 2: Can we write script in .html file?

Tags: magento2, javascript

script code will work in .html file in magento2? 
Thanks advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best idea, I suppose.

.html files are actually used as templates and are set as a property to a RequireJS module that returns Knockout constructors.

So, there is a larger JS that actually integrates the .html within, and it sounds then unnatural to add extra `<script>` tags in .html.

Comment: Its works r what..?